# VBA Program does not give the correct text when statement is false

Tags: vba, excel

My program is suppose to see if the length of the text is within 1 to 31.

If the length is not within 1 to 31 it will return a "FALSE" at e28.

My problem is no matter the length of the text, **it always returns a "TRUE"** please enlighten me on why this is happening.

```
x = Range("b26").Value

count = Len(x) - Len(Replace(x, "-", ""))

If Len(x) - count > 1 & Len(x) - count < 32 Then
    MsgBox Len(x) - count
    Range("e28").Value = "TRUE"
Else
    Range("e28").Value = "FALSE"
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `And` rather than `&` in your `If` condition.

`&` is the string concatenation operator in VBA, and is not appropriate here.

(The fact that `True` evaluates to -1 in VBA also doesn't help matters, and `&` also has a different *precedence* to `And`.)